# How to read multiple characters using scanf_s?

Tags: c, character

I'm supposed to write a program that has an input of 2 characters with a space between them. For some reason, I'm not able to use a single scanf_s because it throws an exception.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it just not possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char character1, character2;

  printf("type in 2 small letters with a space inbetween: ");
  scanf_s("%c %c", &character1, &character2);

  //this part prints big letter version of the one i typed in and its integer value
  printf("%c %d\n", character1 - 32, character1 - 32); 
  printf("%c %d\n", characer2 - 32, character2 - 32);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get from scanf_s?

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov - Exception thrown at 0x0FD398F1 (ucrtbased.dll) in Uloha1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00AA1343.

Comment: According to the Standard ([C11 K.3.5.3.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4)) and [C11 K3.5.3.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2) note 4: "The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that **the c, s, and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments**..."

Comment: @user3121023 `scanf_s("%c %c", &character1, (rsize_t) 1, &character2, (rsize_t) 1);`

Comment: You need to set the preprocessor constant `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to 1 before you include `<stdio.h>` if you want to use the `scanf_s()` function. But i do not think that is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using scanf_s and not regular scanf I need to specify the buffersize like so:

```
scanf_s("%c %c", &character1, 1, &character2, 1);
```

Another option is to use scanf but then I have to suppress warnings:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: `1` is a `int`, `scanf_s()` expects a `rsize_t`. This causes UB. On your platform it may work because they both use 1 register or both have the same size, but it is UB. Cast it to `rsize_t`.